# Unable to trigger geojson marker over a google-map android

Tags: android, google-maps, geojson

I'm showing a geojson file as a layer over a google map android app. Everything works ok, but I'm not be able to trigger on click in geojson markers.

I have adapted the code in:
https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/demo/src/com/google/maps/android/utils/demo/GeoJsonDemoActivity.java

but in line 142:

```
layer.setOnFeatureClickListener(new GeoJsonLayer.GeoJsonOnFeatureClickListener() {
```

I get:

```
cannot resolve method 'setOnFeatureClickListener()'
```

This is my code in onPostExecute;

```
 @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObject) {
            if (jsonObject != null) {
                // Create a new GeoJsonLayer, pass in downloaded GeoJSON file as JSONObject
                mLayer = new GeoJsonLayer(map, jsonObject);
                // Add the layer onto the map
                addColorsToMarkers();
                mLayer.addLayerToMap();


                mLayer.setOnFeatureClickListener(new GeoJsonLayer.GeoJsonOnFeatureClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFeatureClick(GeoJsonFeature feature) {

                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

Do I need to add something else?

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, when I use compile project(':library'), which is come with sample project, it works fine. But if I use 
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+' , it error

the reason is clickable geojson feature is very new, comes out on Jun 9, 2016.
So it has not yet been update into above 0.4.3 library. That is why.
[the new clickable geojson feature just added on Jun 9, 2016](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/pull/286/files)

So the work around is to manually use sample library project into your own project, this is a very hard part, I had try 5 hours to make it work.

first, you will make a jar file out of sample library.

second, copy the lib.jar file to your project.

third, reference the jar file from your project, done

```
dependencies {
compile project(':library')
// Or, fetch from Maven:
//compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'
}
```